# filestream in sql server and C# for aspx

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, filestream

I am developing a website for educational domain. I want to store a document (MS Word or text file) in database in binary format using `Filestream` in SQL Server 2008. but I am unable to retrieve the document in a textbox.

My code is as follows:

```
string path = reader.GetString(0);
SqlFileStream stream1 = new SqlFileStream(path, (byte[])reader.GetValue(1), FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 0);   
StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(stream1);

fs = File.OpenText(path);
string s = fs.ReadToEnd();

txtInput.Text = s;
//lblStatus.Text = "File Succesfully Read!"
fs.Close();
```

This code only works for documents that are stored on the Filesystem not in the database. So I tried the following code:

```
string path = reader.GetString(0);
SqlFileStream stream1 = new SqlFileStream(path, (byte[])reader.GetValue(1), FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 0);   
StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(stream1);

fs = File.OpenText(path);
string s = fs.ReadToEnd();

txtInput.Text = s;
//lblStatus.Text = "File Succesfully Read!"
fs.Close();
```

In this code, it gives error on line `fs = File.OpenText(path);`
as "Access denied to path".

Please help!

Comment: Are you attempting to do a file open on an .MDF file that is use by SQL Server?

Comment: What does your "reader" contain?? What values are you retrieving there??

Comment: I cannot make out any difference in both the code snippets provided !

Answer (score 1):

You should read your data using stream1. The StreamReader and File.OpenText approaches will not work, you can only read filestream data using T-SQL or SqlFileStream object.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to connect to the server Via Windows Authentication. It will not work with SQL Server Authentication. And the Windows User should able access the Shared folder created by SQL Server for storing the Data.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples you are not using your SqlFileStream or StreamReader and just using File.OpenText.

```
StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(stream1);

fs = File.OpenText(path);
string s = fs.ReadToEnd();
```

As File.OpenText only works for files on disk and not SQL filestreams you need to use the stream reader. This should do the trick:

```
StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(stream1);

string s = fs.ReadToEnd();
```